# How to replace a string using Sed?

Tags: sed

Suppose I have a string like this

```
<start><a></a><a></a><a></a></start>
```

I want to replace values inside `<start></start>` like this

```
<start><ab></ab><ab></ab><ab></ab><more></more><vale></value></start>
```

How do I do this using Sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed 's@<start>.*</start>@<start><ab></ab><ab></ab><ab></ab></start>@' file
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/(\<\/?)a\>/\1ab\>/g' yourfile`, though that would get `<a></a>` that was outside `<start>` as well...

Comment: not only **`<a></a> outside <start>`** but also tags like `<ha></ha> or <bla></bla>...`

Comment: I think I fixed it, but backreferences aren't something I normally use, so might be wrong.

Comment: If you are not sure, then put it explicitly to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I get this line with **gnu sed** :

```
sed -r 's#(<start>)(.*)(</start>)#echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed  "s:a>:ab>:g")"\3"#ge'
```

see example:

```
kent$  echo "<start><a></a><a></a><a></a><foo></foo><bar></bar></start>"|sed -r 's#(<start>)(.*)(</start>)#echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed  "s:a>:ab>:g")"\3"#ge'                 
<start><ab></ab><ab></ab><ab></ab><foo></foo><bar></bar></start>
```

**note**

this will replace the tags between `<start>`s which ending with `a` . which worked for your example. but if you have `<aaa></aaa>`:

you could do: (I break it into lines for better reading)

```
sed -r 's#(<start>)(.*)(</start>)
 #echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed "s:<a>:<ab>:g;s:</a>:</ab>:g")"\3"
 #ge'
```

e.g.

```
kent$  echo "<start><a></a><a></a><a></a><aaa></aaa><aba></aba></start>" \
 |sed -r 's#(<start>)(.*)(</start>)#echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed  "s:<a>:<ab>:g;s:</a>:</ab>:g")"\3"#ge'
<start><ab></ab><ab></ab><ab></ab><aaa></aaa><aba></aba></start>
```

Answer (score 0):

grep -rl 'abc' a.txt | xargs sed -i 's/abc/def/g'